# Vectorize integration of pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, vectorization, numerical-integration

I have a `DataFrame` of force-displacement data. The displacement array has been set to the `DataFrame` index, and the columns are my various force curves for different tests.

How do I calculate the work done (which is "the area under the curve")?

I looked at [`numpy.trapz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) which seems to do what I need, but I think that I can avoid looping over each column like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

forces = pd.read_csv(...)
work_done = {}

for col in forces.columns:
    work_done[col] = np.trapz(forces.loc[col], forces.index))
```

I was hoping to create a new `DataFrame` of the areas under the curves rather than a `dict`, and thought that `DataFrame.apply()` or something might be appropriate but don't know where to start looking.

In short:

1. Can I avoid the looping?
2. Can I create a `DataFrame` of work done directly?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could vectorize this by passing the whole `DataFrame` to [`np.trapz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) and specifying the `axis=` argument, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# some random input data
gen = np.random.RandomState(0)
x = gen.randn(100, 10)
names = [chr(97 + i) for i in range(10)]
forces = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=names)

# vectorized version
wrk = np.trapz(forces, x=forces.index, axis=0)
work_done = pd.DataFrame(wrk[None, :], columns=forces.columns)

# non-vectorized version for comparison
work_done2 = {}
for col in forces.columns:
    work_done2.update({col:np.trapz(forces.loc[:, col], forces.index)})
```

These give the following output:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(work_done.T)
#            0
# a -24.331560
# b -10.347663
# c   4.662212
# d -12.536040
# e -10.276861
# f   3.406740
# g  -3.712674
# h  -9.508454
# i  -1.044931
# j  15.165782

pprint(work_done2)
# {'a': -24.331559643023006,
#  'b': -10.347663159421426,
#  'c': 4.6622123535050459,
#  'd': -12.536039649161403,
#  'e': -10.276861220217308,
#  'f': 3.4067399176289994,
#  'g': -3.7126739591045541,
#  'h': -9.5084536839888187,
#  'i': -1.0449311137294459,
#  'j': 15.165781517623724}
```

There are a couple of other problems with your original example. `col` is a column name rather than a row index, so it needs to index the second dimension of your dataframe (i.e. `.loc[:, col]` rather than `.loc[col]`). Also, you have an extra trailing parenthesis on the last line.

---

#### Edit:

You *could* also generate the output `DataFrame` directly by [`.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)ing `np.trapz` to each column, e.g.:

```
work_done = forces.apply(np.trapz, axis=0, args=(forces.index,))
```

However, this isn't really 'proper' vectorization - you are still calling `np.trapz` separately on each column. You can see this by comparing the speed of the `.apply` version against calling `np.trapz` directly:

```
In [1]: %timeit forces.apply(np.trapz, axis=0, args=(forces.index,))
1000 loops, best of 3: 582 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit np.trapz(forces, x=forces.index, axis=0)
The slowest run took 6.04 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.4 µs per loop
```

This isn't an entirely fair comparison, since the second version excludes the extra time taken to construct the `DataFrame` from the output numpy array, but this should still be smaller than the difference in time taken to perform the actual integration.

Comment: Excellent answer thanks. I'll test it at some point over the weekend and tick the answer if it works.

Comment: If i use the `.apply` option, the results of my integration is a Timedelta. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: @rubenbaetens Presumably that's because your columns contain timedelta values. What do you want the type of the result to be? You could, for example, use [`total_seconds()` ](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) to convert the timedelta columns to floats.

Comment: @ali_m my x-axis is a series created as `pd.to_datetime(time1, unit='s')`. In fact, this sometimes even results in the wrong value for integration with the `.apply` option.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get the cumulative integral along a dataframe column using the trapezoidal rule. Alternatively, the following creates a pandas.Series method for doing your choice of Trapezoidal, Simpson's or Romberger's rule ([source](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/metakermit/5720498)):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

#%% Setup Functions

def integrate_method(self, how='trapz', unit='s'):
    '''Numerically integrate the time series.

    @param how: the method to use (trapz by default)
    @return 

    Available methods:
     * trapz - trapezoidal
     * cumtrapz - cumulative trapezoidal
     * simps - Simpson's rule
     * romb - Romberger's rule

    See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html for the method details.
    or the source code
    https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py
    '''
    available_rules = set(['trapz', 'cumtrapz', 'simps', 'romb'])
    if how in available_rules:
        rule = integrate.__getattribute__(how)
    else:
        print('Unsupported integration rule: %s' % (how))
        print('Expecting one of these sample-based integration rules: %s' % (str(list(available_rules))))
        raise AttributeError

    if how is 'cumtrapz':
        result = rule(self.values)
        result = np.insert(result, 0, 0, axis=0)        
    else: 
        result = rule(self.values)
    return result

pd.Series.integrate = integrate_method

#%% Setup (random) data
gen = np.random.RandomState(0)
x = gen.randn(100, 10)
names = [chr(97 + i) for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=names)


#%% Cummulative Integral
df_cummulative_integral = df.apply(lambda x: x.integrate('cumtrapz'))
df_integral = df.apply(lambda x: x.integrate('trapz'))

df_do_they_match = df_cummulative_integral.tail(1).round(3) == df_integral.round(3)

if df_do_they_match.all().all():
    print("Trapz produces the last row of cumtrapz")
```

Comment: copy of http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/metakermit/5720498 , unless you are @metakermit